# Pass clicked item as route parameter to sub component in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, parameter-passing, angular2-routing

I have two angular components called `list` and `list-detail`. I also have two `models` for the `list` and the `list-detail`. Here are the models:

**model list-detail:**

```
export class ListDetail {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}
```

**model list:**

```
import { ListDetail } from './list-detail';

export class List {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    items: ListDetail[];
}
```

In my `list` component I loop the whole list and display it like this:

**component list template:**

```
<div class="list">
    <div class="list__item" *ngFor="let item for list">
        {{item.name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

My output would be something like this:

- List 1
- List 2
- List 3

Now my goal is it, when I click on a `list`, to route to the list-detail component and pass the clicked item as route parameter, so I can display it there.

This is how my `appRoutes` look like:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'list', component: ListComponent,
        childrend: [
            { path: 'list-detail', component: ListDetailComponent }
        ]
    }
];
```

So what I tried is follow in the template of my `list` component for passing the clicked list as `route` `parameter` to the `list-detail` component, that I found in an question on the internet: https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/routing/query_params.html

```
<div class="list__item" *ngFor="let item for list" (click)="let selected = item" [routerLink]="['./list-detail', selected]">
```

I added a `(click)` to assign the clicked item to a new variable and than used `[routerLink]` with the path and the `selected` to pass it to the `list-detail`.

**Problem:** Now I don't understand, how I should use the `parameter` in my `list-detail` component to display it's name on the template of the `list-detail` component? And is the way how I try to pass the `list` to the sub component the right one? Hope for some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

1. Set a key in route path `{ path: 'list-detail/:selected', component: ListDetailComponent }`
2. Subscribe in component to route params and look for that key

```js
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute)

ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params.subscribe(params => this.selected = params['selected']);
}
```

Comment: Any errors / wrong behaviour? You can try to replace `[routerLink]="['./list-detail', selected]"` into `[routerLink]="['./list-detail', item]"`

Answer (score 0):

1. `RouterLink` only works on `<a>` tags. You should instead call a function in your component on click of the list. See https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigate for information regarding triggering navigation in a component.
2. You can only pass string as route parameters. So rather than passing the object `item`, try passing `item.id` or `item.name` instead.